# Selenium "No module named 'selenium' " even after pip3 install

Tags: python, selenium

I do not know why I cannot `import selenium` even after I pip install it. 
Does anyone know how else I can troubleshoot it or how to fix this?

I am using Mac OS and python 3.7.4

```
python3                                                  
Python 3.7.4 

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
>>>
pip3 install selenium                                                                          
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium)
```

UPDATE

I was kind of messing around and one of the things that I did helped make it work. I am not sure which of the items but if someone can explain it so I understand this in the future, that would be appreciated.

1. I did `brew doctor` which outputted the following

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.


Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python
```

2. `brew link --overwrite python`
3. `vi /usr/local/bin/pip` 
   and changed `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7` to `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3` and it worked
   I am guessing my issue is that I have two instances of python installed so it was downloading the selenium library to a difference python version (3.7) instead of 3 which is what I wanted.

Let me know if you think this was the issue or if you can clarify what you may think is the issue

Comment: Are you sure you install it for the same python instance you are running the script? For example running `which pip` should show which pip instance is being used.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed  and pip may install module for different Python. You can use Python to install it `python3 -m pip install selenium`

Comment: yes I used `pip install selenium` and `pip3 install selenium`; both says requirement already satisfied but when I run python3, it doesn't work. Is there a path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try pip install, instead of pip3

Answer (score 0):

Please check the pip version using command

```
pip --version
```

Mostly, pip is associated with python version 2.7 while pip3 is associated with python3

So, try -

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Since pip will install it for python2 while pip3 will install for python3 as you are using python3 in the question.